# Subsheaves of constant sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a connected topological space. I am looking for examples of a locally constant subsheaf (of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces) of a constant sheaf (of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces) on X, which is not a constant sheaf. This is probably not a research level question and I had asked the question on [Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768111/subsheaves-of-constant-sheaves), but did not get an answer. Any hint/reference will be most welcome.

Comment: This does not exist (assuming $X$ is a reasonable space). The monodromy representation of a constant sheaf is trivial, so any subrepresentation will be trivial as well.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks. That answers my question.

Comment: @RobertoPignatelli Are you saying that if I take the intersection of the constant sheaf with the ideal sheaf and this will be an example of a locally constant subsheaf of the constant sheaf? If so, I think the intersection will be 0.

Comment: I think I misread your question. I interpreted locally constant as locally trivial, I mean invertible. Sorry